# Stop snapshot listener

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a snapshot listener and I want to stop it when I dismissing my `ViewController`, I know I need to use `listener.remove()` but I want to call it in the `ViewWillDisappear()` function.

I want to declare a var in my `ViewController`:

```
var listener = ListenerRegistration?.self
```

and then in the listener func type :

```
listener = openInstanceRef?.collection("MyDishes").addSnapshotListener( ... )
```

but I get this error :

`Cannot assign value of type 'ListenerRegistration?' to type 'ListenerRegistration?.Type'`

if I try to remove the .self and type `ListenerRegistration?()` instead I get this error in the declaration of listener  :

```
`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ListenerRegistration?' with no arguments`
```

but `swift` won't offer me any initialisers that do get arguments

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in Swift is:

```
listener.remove()
```

See the [Firestore documentation on removing listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise like this instead

```
private var listener = ListenerRegistration!
```

and if its optional just remove the parenthesis

```
private var listener = ListenerRegistration? = nil
```